# vlc web plugin mouse event for IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, web, mouseevent, vlc

Use vlc activex plugin for IE webpage,I have tried very hard for catching mouse click event in the video area on the webpage.
For onmouseover/onmousemove/onmouseout can be listened.
But onclick/ondbclick/onmousedown/onmouseup can not be.

I have tried with local programing, attach the follow codes in file \modules\video_output\msw\events.c under the code:`case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:`

```
{
                POINT pt;
                pt.x = GET_X_LPARAM(msg.lParam);
                pt.y = GET_Y_LPARAM(msg.lParam);
                ClientToScreen(msg.hwnd, &pt);
                ScreenToClient(vd->sys->hparent, &pt);

                PostMessage(vd->sys->hparent, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, msg.wParam, MAKELPARAM(pt.x, pt.y));
 }
```

But still not work.
Is there anyone farmiliar with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

:)
Yes, you are in trouble. 
You only found questions, and then tried to come out with an answer.
It appears that the most recent events are available in vlc as in others activeX objects. 
So, try using drag events, and mouse whell events. Probably you must change the original requirements, but with some "out of the box thinking" you can do it.
Make sure you use IE original event registration methods.
Thanks for this site, thanks for the reviewers, this is my small contribution.
Check it, and comment: http://tijaquim.blogspot.pt/2015/12/activex-mouse-events-with-mouse.html